# I need to provide to separate exception statements. 1. empty string and 2. valid numeric data

Tags: java, string, numberformatexception

```
try{
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            System.out.println(" Enter the Amount of articles to be ordered.");
            amount = reader.readLine();

            if(amount.trim().isEmpty()){
                System.out.println("Amount Entered is Empty");
            }

            for(int count=0;count<amount.length();count++){
                if(!Character.isDigit(amount.charAt(count))){
                    throw new NumberFormatException();
                }
            }            
            order.validateAmount(amount);
        }catch(NumberFormatException numbere){
            System.out.println("Either Number format is uncorrect or String is Empty, Try Again.");
    }
```

The above code gives me single println() statement for both empty string exception and invalid numeric data exception, which I don't want. I want separate println() statements for both exception. how to get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You could either use **two different exceptions**, for instance `NumberFormatException` and `IllegalArgumentException` and do **two different `catch`-clauses**.

   ```
       ...
       if (amount.isEmpty())
           throw new IllegalArgumentException();
       ...

   } catch (NumberFormatException numbere) {
       System.out.println("Either Number format is uncorrect, Try Again.");
   } catch (IllegalArgumentException empty) {
       System.out.println("String is empty, Try Again.");
   }
   ```
2. Use the same exception but **with different messages**:

   ```
   try {
       BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
               System.in));
       System.out.println(" Enter the Amount of articles to be ordered.");
       String amount = reader.readLine();

       if (amount.trim().isEmpty()) {
           System.out.println("Amount Entered is Empty");
       }

       if (amount.isEmpty())
           throw new IllegalArgumentException("String is empty.");


       for (int count = 0; count < amount.length(); count++)
           if (!Character.isDigit(amount.charAt(count)))
               throw new IllegalArgumentException("Number format incorrect.");

       order.validateAmount(amount);
   } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
       System.out.println(e.getMessage() + " Try again.");
   }
   ```
3. Or, you could **roll your own `Exception`** with two different constructors, and a flag stating if the exception was due to a bad number or an empty string.

Comment: Let me know if you want me to elaborate on any of the alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Since an empty string is an 'expected' exception I would not use an exception but check for it:

```
if ( amount.trim().equals( string.empty) )
{
   System.out.println("string empty" );
}
else
{
   //do your other processing here
}
```

Another check for emptiness would be `amount.trim().length == 0`

If you really want to use exceptions:

```
if( amount.trim().equals( string.empty) )
{
   throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Amount is not given" );
}
```

and add another catch()

```
}
catch( NumberFormatException numbere)
{
}
catch( IllegalArgumentException x )
{
  // Amount not given
}
```

Comment: There is a `String.isEmpty` method. You don't need to compare against the empty string.

Comment: What we need to import to handle InvalidArgumentException. I didn't find any javadoc for that.

Comment: Nothing. It is in the `java.lang` package (which is automatically imported by the JVM)

Comment: @aioobe I had string.IsNullOrEmpty() since I guessed the wrong language first :-)

Comment: What's that? C#? wouldn't you get a null pointer if `string` was actually null? *confused*.

Comment: string.IsNullOrEmpty( amount ) would be the correct call. Is NullOrEmpty is a static function in the string class. Acutally, IsNullOrWhiteSpace would be even better.